# how to make the data in a file inorder?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed, spreadsheet

I have a testfile.txt as below

```
/path/        345 firstline
/path2/     346     second line
/path3/ 347   third line having spaces
/path4/  3456 fourthline
```

Now I want to make it as below

```
/path/,345,firstline
/path2/,346,second line
/path3/,347,third line having spaces
/path4/,3456,fourthline
```

According the above output, The data should be formed with 3 columns and all columns separated with commas.There may be one or more spaces between the columns in the input file.Example,

> **/path/** and **3456**

can be separated by 2 tabs also. The third column contains the spaces as it is.

Can anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sed` command to achieve this:

I tried this and it worked for me:

```
sed 's/[ \t]\+/,/' testfile.txt | sed 's/[ \t]\+/,/'
```

It replaces only the first and second instances of spaces or tabs in your file.

---

> Update

`sed` (stream editor) uses commands to perform editing. The first parameter `'s/[ \t]\+/,/'` is the command that is used for replacing one expression with another. Splitting this command further:

> Syntax: **s/expression1/expression2/**

```
s - substitute
/ - expression separator
[ \t]\+ - (expression1) this is the expression to find and replace (This regular expression matches one or more space or tab characters)
, - (expression2) this is what you want to replace the first expression with
```

When the above command is run, on each line the first instance of your expression is replaced. Because you need the second delimiter also to be replaced, I piped the output of the first `sed` command to another similar command. This replaced the second delimiter with a `,`.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks,it is working as expected.

Comment: can you also elaborate the command how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -s ' ' <data |sed -e 's/\s/,/' -e  's/\s/,/'
/path/,345,firstline
/path2/,346,second line
/path3/,347,third line having spaces
/path4/,3456,fourthline
```

Not the best way to do this, but it will generate the desired output.